# Jquery script not loading at runtime edit: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this script not loading at runtime or after I activate the submit button? I pulled it from a larger script and it seems it should run adhoc, but the variables do not appear in the console after pageload and the form does not submit.  I have confirmed jquery is loaded properly before hand. Any one have any idea here?

edit: Moved the script to the bottom of the page, now it runs but Im receiving a

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Not sure if I should make a new thread or leave this open, whats the preferred protocol?

```
    $('form.sidebar-form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var email = $.trim( $form.find('input[name="emailAddress"]').val() );
        var $response = $form.find('.form-response');

        // Loading Animation
        var iter = 1;
        var interval = 500;
        var timeout, loading;
        loading = function() {
            var base = '&bull;&nbsp;';
            var text = '&nbsp;';
            for(var i = 1; i <= iter; i++) {
                text = text + base;
            }
            $response.html(text);
            if( iter === 3 ) {
                iter = 0;
            } else {
                iter++;
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(loading, interval);
        };
        timeout = setTimeout(loading, interval);

        // Check Email Address
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.\d\+]+@([\w-\d]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
        if( !emailReg.test( email ) || email == '' ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            $response.html('<span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>');
            return;
        }

        // Eloqua Form Action
        var elqAction = 'https://s1224369867.t.eloqua.com/e/f2';

        // Post Data
        var postData = {
            elqFormName       : 'var-gameserver-0315',
            elqSiteId         : 'hidden',
            elqCampaignId     : '',
            emailAddress      : email,
            preferredLanquage : 'English',
            singleCheckbox10  : 'on',
            hiddenField       : 'var-Gameserver'
        };

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            headers: { 'cache-control': 'no-cache' },
            type: 'POST',
            url: elqAction
        }).always(function(data, status) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            if( status === 'success' || status === 'parsererror' ) {
                $response.html('<span class="success">Thanks for your interest in var</span>');

            } else {
                $response.html('<span class="error">There was a problem communicating with our server</span>');
            }
        });

    });
```

// HTML

```
                    <div class="sidebar">

                    <p>Please fill out the from below.</p>

                    <form class="sidebar-form">
                        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address<span style="">*</span></label>
                    <input id="field0" name="emailAddress" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='EmailAddress' />" />
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input id="field1" name="firstName" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='FirstName' />" />
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="field2" name="lastName" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='LastName' />" />
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input id="field3" name="title" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='Title1' />" />
                        <label for="company">Company<span style="">*</span></label>
                    <input id="field4" name="company" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='Company' />" />
                        <label for="Phone">Phone<span style="">*</span></label>
                    <input id="field5" name="Phone" type="text" value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='Business_Phone1' />" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-submit" style="font-size: 100%; height: 24px; width: 100px" />
                    </form>
                    <div class="form-response"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you running this inside a `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` or the equivalent `$(function () { ... });`?

Comment: Are you running this locally (localhost?) or from a web server? If locally, how? (lamp/mamp/wamp stack?)

Comment: Gibberish - tested on both localhost, and from eloqua hosted environment

GregL - no luck here

Comment: *"but the variables do not appear in the console after pageload"* - Why would the variables appear in the console? They're local variables inside a function that won't be called until a submit event occurs on the `'form.sidebar-form'` element (and even then the function will only be called if you run the above code after the form's markup has been parsed).

Comment: nnnnnn - Ive been hitting test the submit button before Im viewing console vars with 'for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}'

Comment: As per my last comment, they're *local* variables in that function. Local variables don't end up as properties of `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting you code in a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ... your code here ...
});
```

It looks like the div with class .form-response is not in your form tag.

This line of code

```
var $response = $form.find('.form-response');
```

should be

```
var $response = $('.form-response');
```

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sifewe/2/edit).

Comment: I have tried this and the equivalent mentioned by GregL Niether work for me

Comment: does you form have a class of `class="sidebar-form"`?

Comment: Im using '<form class="sidebar-form">'

Comment: can you post your html?